# How to display the value of a variable in plotly python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Already having made multiple plots using plotly-python, I wish to do a rather simple task: Display the value of a variable in the HTML output page.

Imagine a number (in large font) on the top of the [dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh9Fh.png) below showing the total costs . Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please share if you have done anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be much more helpful if you showed us your code, an easy solution to your problem is to have an HTML.div in the layout and set it with an id, and with the corresponding ID, create a callback with the ID as the output that returns the value of the variable.

An example:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='my-output'),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])

x = "hi"

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-input', component_property='children')
)
def update_output_div(input):
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```